How would I calculate the damage someone suffered from various strikes?
So, I’ve been developing a TTRPG and am wanting to present a realistic fantasy world. This doesn’t mean fantastic things wouldn’t happen - demigods can swing swords at the speed of light. But when they do so the consequences are realistic - the mass destruction of large areas, for example.
My question is this: how would I calculate the force of an edged weapon striking armor, and the damage the individual in armor took? If you can, I would be interesting in knowing the same for both blunt weapons and projectiles. If possible (if not, that’s okay), I would love to have equations I could reference to use for myself in the development process.
To be clear, all of this is with the intention of taking this math and newfound understanding to then take certain necessary abstractions without sacrificing realism.

VTC - This is a crunch question, not a worldbuilding question. You are wanting us to help with a game mechanic as oppose to building a world.

Yeah, it's not a worldbuilding question. Worse, though the equations L.Dutch gave you represent the general condition, they're far, far, far from adequate because you're caring far, far, far too much about tiny details. E.G. all plate armor is not equal (type of steel, amount of carbon in the steel, thickness of the steel, skill of the armorer), nor are the wearers (agility, training, musculature, constitution, even attitude), and then there's circumstantial conditions (firmness of the ground, quality of the blade, angle of impact...) there are hundreds if not thousands of variables.

... And just to make things worse, "damage" isn't quantifiable numerically in the real world, nor is an individual's ability (or lack) to work/fight through the damage. How do you represent a good bang on the head, or a terrible bruise, or even a broken finger? How do you represent the effects of adrenaline, fear, focus, and belief? There's a reason why Dungeons & Dragons (and pretty much every video game designer in all of history) has simplified all this by assigning basic numbers to everything - you shouldn't need the Frontier supercomputer just to calculate damage.

To add to JBH, there's reasons (realism for one, convenience, excitement and anticipation in the hands of the DM) that a roll of the die is convention. Sitting in the corner with a calculator would seem to have great potential to disrupt suspension of disbelief in the game (and the fun).

You can estimate the force by knowing the mass M of your object, sword in this case, its velocity v and the time it takes to stop after it hits, you can use the relationship
$M\Delta v=F\Delta t$
By knowing the kinetic energy
$K=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$
of the object, you can also get a first order estimate if the armor would get damaged or not, by comparing the available energy with the energy needed to plastically deform the impacted material: if plastic deformation doesn't happen, the armor will work as a spring, which usually would not result in an immediate damage.
To avoid diving into nitty-gritty details of deformation calculation and so on (people who do it as a job to design crash resistant cars spend a lot of time on it), just make a rough scale of momentum/energy: up to here nothing happens, from here to there it's a light damage and so on.

So, "sword swung at lightspeed" falls solidly in the "heavy damage/nuclear fusion with the atmosphere before it even reaches the armor so it kinda doesn't matter because everyone in a 30-mile radius will be dead... unless the demigod can resist fusion" category, right?
